# Need help about using WebBrowser

Tags: c#, wpf, internet-explorer, browser

I Would need some help. Currently, I have to open internet explorer after clicking on an hyperlink (situated in FlowDocument).
The click on the hyperlink is successful (it raises an event, I have the Navigate URI without problem)

What must I do to open internet explorer at the URL specified ? 
I use webBrowser.navigate, that asks a navigate URI (I got it), a string of the targetFrameName (??), a postData grid of Bytes (no idea neither of what I have to put), and a string representing an additional Headers.

If any one could help me... that would be great!!
Thanks!

Flo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AdvancedCustomTreeViewLyt.aspx) example.

This application displays an article from Wikipedia after clinking on specified city name. It is mostly article about treeview but it has a web browser part that might be interesting for you.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I read it, but the author doesn't explain a lot how to process to play with hyperlinks, he kept focused on the Treeview, unfortunately...
BTW, thanks!

Comment: @Flo Yes, but did you try download the code? Look in the file `Window1.xaml` and `Window1.xaml.cs`, there are a few lines of code you need.

Comment: I managed to display my internet page in a new Frame, but not opening internet explorer... This is not what I was looking for, but that helps me a lot!!!!! Thx ;)

Comment: @Flo Maybe you just want: `System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore.exe", @"http://bing.com");`

Comment: YEES ! That's it!! I just find the solution. I use
Process.Start((sender as Hyperlink).NavigateUri.ToString())
and it understands which software it must launch to open the file!
Thanks a lot !